# C: Bus Error between function returns and execution goes back to parent function

Tags: c, pthreads, ncurses

To simplify the problem as much as possible, I have two functions, a parent that calls the child. Everything executes okay till it gets to the return of the child function. After that I get a Bus Error.

```
int main () {

    game();
    
    // this doesn't get executed and program fails with bus error
    printf("Execute 2");

    return 1;
}

int game () {
    game_t GameInfo = {.level = 1, .score = 0, .playerCh = 0, .playerX = 1, .playerY = 1};
    gameLevel(&GameInfo);
    mvprintw(1,1, "Executed");
    // code works up to here and get's executed properly
    return 1;
};

void gameLevel (game_t *GameInfo) {    
    // determine the size of the game field
    int cellCols = COLS / 3;
    int cellRows = (LINES / 3) - 2;

    GameInfo -> playerX = 1;
    GameInfo -> playerY = 1;

    generateMaze(0);

    int solved = 0;

    int level = GameInfo -> level;


    // default player position
    getPlayerDefault(GameInfo);

    pthread_t enemies_th;
    pthread_create(&enemies_th, NULL, enemies, (void *)GameInfo);
    // enemies(&level);

    while (solved == 0 && GameInfo -> collision != 1) {
        printGameInfo(GameInfo);
        noecho();
        char move = getch();
        echo();
        if (GameInfo -> collision != 1) {
            if (checkMoveValidity(move, GameInfo) == 1) {
                solved = movePlayer(move, GameInfo);
                if (solved == 1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (solved == 1) {
        pthread_cancel(enemies_th);
        GameInfo->level++;
        gameLevel(GameInfo);
    } else {
        // game over
        pthread_cancel(enemies_th);
        return;
    }
}
```

Now, the code is much more complicated than here, but I think that shouldn't have any influence on this (?) as it executes properly, until the return statement. There is also ncurses and multithreading, quite complex custom structures, but it all works, up until that point. Any ideas ?

Tried putting print statements after each segment of code, everything worked up until this.

Comment: Does this piece of code really reproduce the aforementioned problem? I sincerely doubt that.

Comment: Well, now you just "threw your entire code" in here. Best you can do is to debug it a little, come up with the minimal amount of code which still reproduces the problem, and then post it here along with a brief description of your debug efforts. Whilst doing so, you might actually end up figuring out the problem on your on.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb Okay, thanks, I actually thought about that, before posting here. I already debugged and dumbed it down, to the version that was before that. All of the functions besides `game()` return properly, including the one that runs on other thread, everything up to that final return statement executes properly, and as C is by default singlethreaded, all of these things shouldn't have any influence, ergo the first version of the code posted.

Comment: With regards to "the first version of the code posted" - like I said - if it doesn't reproduce the problem, then it is useless for the readers here. You need to provide an MVP - a **minimal** amount of code which **still** reproduces the problem.

Comment: My guess is that the enemies thread is still running and accessing the `GameInfo` variable that belongs to `game()` after the main thread has returned to the `main()` function and the lifetime of that variable has expired. I suggest using `pthread_join()` to join the enemies thread after cancelling it. The tail recursion in `gameLevel()` also seems unnecessary. I suggest returning a status to `game()` and letting that function decide whether to start the next level.

Answer (score 1):

`pthread_cancel()` doesn't terminate the requested thread immediately. The only way to know that a cancelled thread has terminated is to call `pthread_join()`. If the thread is left running, it will interfere with use of the `GameInfo` variable in the next level of the game if the current level is solved, or may use the `GameInfo` variable beyond its lifetime if the current level was not solved and the main thread returns back to the `main()` function.

To make sure the old enemies thread has terminated, add calls to `pthread_join()` to the `gameLevel()` function as shown below:

```
    if (solved == 1) {
        pthread_cancel(enemies_th);
        pthread_join(enemies_th);
        GameInfo->level++;
        gameLevel(GameInfo);
    } else {
        // game over
        pthread_cancel(enemies_th);
        pthread_join(enemies_th);
        return;
    }
```

---

The use of tail recursion in `gameLevel()` seems unnecessary. I recommend returning the `solved` value and letting the `game()` function start the next level:

In `game()`:

```
    while (gameLevel(&GameInfo)) {
        GameInfo.level++;
    }
```

In `gameLevel()`:

```
int gameLevel(game_t *GameInfo) {
   /* ... */
   pthread_cancel(enemies_th);
   pthread_join(enemies_th);
   return solved;
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately it now throws sometimes segmentation error, sometimes, bus error. Basically, the there is collision when position of enemy is the same as the position of the player. When this happens, player is usually inside of the while, waiting for getch(); then the second condition prevents next loop, and it goes into canceling and joining the thread (which I added, thanks for that) and it throws the error.

Comment: @MichalGally You probably need to synchronize access to the GameInfo shared between threads.